# Receiving customized response and file from REST web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I'm trying to create some REST web services with Java in order to send data, do calculations on the server, and return the result. In a first stage I send and receive information as an excel file (in the future I prefer to use XML or JSON).
Well, after a lots of hours trying it, and reading lots of posts, it seems I'm very close to achieve it, but I don't know how to obtain the final response of the server.
I have a service like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile(@QueryParam("IDfile") String IDfile) { 
    if(IDfile.trim().length() == 0 || IDfile == null) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("IDfile cannot be blank").build();
    }        

    String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\FilesWebservice\\" + IDfile;
    Boolean sortida = false;
    try {
        prova prueba = new prova();
        sortida = prueba.prova(uploadedFileLocation); //this creates an xls file as response
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error" + ex.toString());
        Logger.getLogger(ServiceResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if (sortida) {
        File file = new File("C:\\FilesWebservice\\out\\prediction.xls"); // the File path you want to serve.
        return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
          .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
          .build();
    } else
        return Response.status(500).entity("It was unable to calculate (Ask God for the reason)").build();

}
```

It works OK, if I send a GET through the browser I receive the file in my downloads folder, but I need to consume the service with another application. Thus, I'm developing a client with Netbeans, and then, NB created automatic code according to my web service. In this case I have:

```
public <T> T getFile(Class<T> responseType, String IDfile) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (IDfile != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("IDfile", IDfile);
    }
    resource = resource.path("test");

    Builder builder = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    Invocation invocation = builder.buildGet();

    return resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE).get(responseType);
}
```

Maybe I added some lines, I can't remember now. Anyway, the service returns a status code, a customised message and the file as attachment. I want to read at least the status code and obviously save the file, but I don't know how can I do it.
I tried to do:

```
    MyJerseyClientAlgA client = new MyJerseyClientAlgA("192.168.1.30");
    Object response = client.getFile(Response.class, "3cphkhfu.xls");
```

but it was unsuccessful to extract the information I need from 'response'. 
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:

Thanks @LutzHorn for your reply. I'm not sure if I understand well your proposal, I'll do some tests and if I find a solution I'll post under my question. Anyway, I generated again the automatic code for consuming the REST service, that is:

```
public <T> T getFile(Class<T> responseType, String IDfile) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (IDfile != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("IDfile", IDfile);
    }
    resource = resource.path("test");
    return resource.get(responseType);
}
```

but I have an error in the last line, it indicates:
cannot find symbol

symbol: method get(Class)

so I changed this line for

return resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE).get(responseType);

but I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: Don't `return resource.request` but assign it to a local variable. NetBeans will help you with setting the correct type of this variable. Then you can access the status code and the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some hours searching and testing, this piece of code works. I don't know if it is the best solution, but it does exactly what I want: extract the status and save the file returned by the web service.

```
public void getFile(String IDfile) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    if (IDfile != null) {
        resource = resource.queryParam("IDfile", IDfile);
    }
    resource = resource.path("test");
    Invocation inv = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE).buildGet();
    Response rp = inv.invoke();
    InputStream attachment = null;
    try {
        if (rp.getStatus() == 200) { 
            attachment = rp.readEntity(InputStream.class); //This method can be invoked only once unless you buffer the response...
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(attachment); //website.openStream()
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://FilesWebservice/solution.xls");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);                
        } else {
            System.out.println(rp.getStatus());
        }
    } catch ( Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally {
        rp.close();
    }

}
```